# Adding Background Color to bodyWithCircleOfRadius

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, collision

My collisions are acting a bit weird and I was wondering if it the bodyWithCircleOfRadius wasn't in the correct place. So I'm looking for a way to add a background color to it so that I can at least see it and fix it's size/position if need be.

It would be great if this works for bodyWithPolygonFromPath, etc.

Comment: Add skView.showsPhysics = YES to your view controller to see an outline of the physic bodies in your scene.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted.